# How to create web pages or program with LaTeX math style?

Tags: latex

I just wondering, how can write web applications or web pages using LaTeX-styled math? please don't refer to LaTeX2png. i want a text formation tool or script, like [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [MathJax](http://craicpropagation.blogspot.com/2009/12/still-more-latex-on-web.html) or [KaTeX](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX) could be just what you want.

Comment: You're so welcome.  All credit to the folks that actually wrote it, of course.  I'm just the hyperlinker.